# Fetching server related info through IPMI protocol

Tags: ipmitool, ipmi, out-of-band

I'm working on IPMI protocol which communicates with a BMC board present in a server. I've got a doubt which basically is that can we get all the server related info(majorily boot options and reseting the system) through IPMI protocol using its commands(including RAW commands) ?

I tried to search it on internet but I didn't get much info (even on oracle's website) !

So if the answer is yes, please redirect me to the resource.
What I want is clear elaboration of the commands so that I can make use of it.

Comment: The question has tag `ipmitool` so I guess the question is off-topic for stack overflow and should be asked at `Super User` or `Server Fault`. Nevertheless - ipmitool can set boot options and trigger a reset as well. Try `ipmitool chassis help`. If the question is actually related to development then please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, the IPMI Spec.

http://www.intel.com.tw/content/www/tw/zh/servers/ipmi/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.html

For an example:
ipmitool bmc info
Equal to ipmitool raw 0x06 0x01
0x06 is Network Function Code 
0x01 is commad of NetFn
Find section,Get Device Command, to parse response data